# enable screen share in electron without using nodeIntegration true

Tags: electron

I am creating a native app in electron. For this i have created a BrowserWindow and loaded url into it with nodeIntegration false. In my website everything is working bine if opened in browser. However, if i run same in electron, the screen share is not working. I tried to implement it using some online references like using 'preload' to load js file. But nothing works

> I am using latest Electron for this.

**main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'loadScripts.js')
    }
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL("https://abc.xyz.com/dkajd");
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}
app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
});
```

**loadScript.js**

```
const { desktopCapturer } = require('electron');
let mediaSources = null;

desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] },(err, sources) => {
  mediaSources = sources;
});
```

Comment: You can't `require` if you've turned off node integration, so you can't make this work. You'll have to turn it on. If you're loading an external page, you should stick it in a `webview` tag instead, so you can't disable node for that page only

Comment: @pushkin i am able to use `require` in loadScript.js as it is injected into page on page load (check main.js file under `preload` value). Also `nodeIntegration` is by default enabled in `preload` scripts. But my issue is, i am not able to start screen share from external link. How can i perform it?

Comment: oh apologies - I completely missed that you have a preload script. Details are a little different, but something similar has come up before (see [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11922)). consider posting an issue on their github. Admittedly, I've never used desktopCapturer.